# Join two larger dataframes into smaller multindex dataframe according to matching row numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using recordlinkage to find matches between two unequally-sized dataframes, which outputs a multindex dataframe (features) containing the corresponding row number for matches in df_a in the first index (left) and likewise for df_b in the second index (right). I want to merge only matches found in df_a and df_b at the correct index in features, like so:

**df_a**

```
      col_a col_b col_c
a           
b
c
d
e
```

**df_b**

```
      col_1 col_2 col_3
1           
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**features**

```
                match
   left  right 
    a     2      
          3
    b     7
          8
          9
```

To end up with
**merge2**

```
               match col_a col_b col_c col_1 col_2 col_3
   left  right 
    a     2      
          3
    b     7
          8
          9
```

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
for i in range(0,in_a_lines,chunks):
    if i < in_a_lines - chunks:
          df_a_subset = df_a.iloc[i:i+chunks]
    else:
          df_a_subset = df_a.iloc[i:in_a_lines]

    indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
    indexer.block(left_on = [comp_left], right_on = [comp_right])
    pairs_subset = indexer.index(df_a_subset, df_b)

    comp = recordlinkage.Compare()
    comp.string(left_on = comp_left, right_on = comp_right, method='jarowinkler', threshold = 0.85)
    features = comp.compute(pairs_subset, df_a_subset, df_b).rename_axis(['left', 'right'])
    
    print(str(i+chunks)+"/"+str(in_a_lines)+"\nPotential matches: "+str(len(features)))


    merge1 = df_b.join(features, on=['right'])
    merge2 = df_a_subset.join(merge1, on = ['left'])
  
    merge2.to_csv(out_csv,
          header = None,
          index = None,
          mode='a',
          chunksize=chunks)
```

Comment: Why does left 1 match right 2 and 4?

Comment: recordlinkage.Compare() takes two single index dataframes and finds partial string matches, outputting a multindex dataframe, the indices determined by where it found a match between those two. In this case, this means the entry at df_a row 1 matched entries at df_b rows 2 and 4. I'll edit it to be clearer these are two separate indices.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the order mixed up, left dataframe needs to call the join:

```
merge1 = features.join(df_a_subset, on='left', how = 'inner')
merge2 = merge1.join(df_b, on='right', how = 'inner')
```

In case you want to delete the rows containing recordlinkage's match conditions, add

```
merge2 = merge2.drop(merge2.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)
```